# Column level encryption in hive using KMS

Tags: hadoop, encryption, hive

I am looking for some help, in implementing column level encryption in Hive using KMS (Exactly similar to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7934).  While am clear with the 2nd part in the referred URL, am not clear with setting up KMS, and "TBLPROPERTIES ('hive.encrypt.keynames'='hive.k1')" part in the create table script.

Would appreciate for some help please.  I have searched over stackoverflow, but couldn't get a solution.

Thanks

Yuva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hive.k1 is the kms key name that will be used to encrypt and decrypt the hive columns.